# SSH public key authentication with Powershell

Tags: ssh, debian, powershell

I'm trying to create a SSH connection between my personal laptop running with *Windows 11* and *Powershell 7.3.9* and
my VPS running on *Debian 12 (bookworm)*. I'm not using Putty on purpose.

I first wanted to get clear of all existing ssh keys (I'm beginning with SSH and made several tries) and the tried to
create and copy a new one, everything seemed to work as planned but when I try to log in, it keeps asking me my password,
and if I authorize only public key connection I get `permission denied`

`sshd_config` on my server is basically the same as the one provided by
[k4yt3x](https://github.com/k4yt3x/sshd_config/blob/master/sshd_config)

---

#### Erase old keys

- **server :** delete keys in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- **local :** `Remove-Item -Path $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\* -Force`

---

#### Create new key

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f C:\Users\user\.ssh\id_rsa -N ''`

---

#### Copy id on server

I wrote and executed this script in *Powershell*:

```
# Public key path
$publicKeyPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub"

# Server user name, port and domain
$username = "user"
$domain = "domaine"
$port = "port"

# Read public key content
$publicKey = Get-Content $publicKeyPath

# Concatenate public key content with username
$sshContent = "$username`:$publicKey"

# Send the public key to the server and add it to authorized_keys
$sshContent | ssh -p $port "$username@$domain" "cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

then I checked permissions on my server

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

---

Despite all this, password is still asked on login.

Here is the result of `ssh -v -i 'path_to_private_key' user@domain` :

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to domaine [adresse_ip] port XXXX.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to domaine:port as 'user'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:key
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[domain]:port' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa RSA SHA256:key explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-dss,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com (unrecognised)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\user\\.ssh\\id_rsa RSA SHA256:key explicit
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
user@domaine: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I found this line with `journalctl` :
`Date lateHour hostname sudo[2239907]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; logname=user uid=1000 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=user rhost=  user=user`

I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: `authorized_keys` should NOT be set to `user:pubfilecontent`; it should get _only_ the pubfile content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new key
`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"`

When you run the commands above, you’ll be prompted with the following lines asking to enter a location to save the file.

`type $env:USERPROFILE\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | ssh {IP-ADDRESS} "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"`

Replace {IP-ADDRESS} with the server IP address.

If you don’t already have a ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file at the destination location, run the Linux commands below to create one. Re-run the command above again to copy your key to the server.
`touch ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: You don't need `touch`; `cat >>file` creates the file if it doesn't exist (as does `>`). You do need to `mkdir .ssh` first if _it_ doesn't exist, and usually to `chmod` it as OP did.